# Updating DataGridView from DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a `DataGridView` whose DataSource is a `DataTable`. I manually create the columns for the `DataGridView` rather than auto-generating them, because I'm creating sub-headers for some of the columns.

I also have a form in which a user enters various pieces of information. That information gets sent to a class that does calculations and returns the results into the `DataTable`.

The row successfully gets added to the `DataGridView`, however, each of the cells are empty. Yet when I debug the program and look into the `DataTable`, there is clearly values in the table. But when I look into the `DataGridView`...as expected, there are just empty (`null`) cells.

I've tried `dataGridView.Refresh()` and `dataGridView.Update()` to no avail. How can I get the information to appear on the `DataGridView`?

This is the piece of code where I build the `DataGridView`:

```
        //BUILD COLUMNS
        mainDataGridView.Columns.Add("OType", "Type");
        mainDataGridView.Columns.Add("OLoad", "Load Factor");
        mainDataGridView.Columns.Add("WCMen", "Men");
        mainDataGridView.Columns.Add("WCWomen", "Women");
        mainDataGridView.Columns.Add("WCTotal", "Total");
        mainDataGridView.Columns.Add("LavMen", "Men");
        mainDataGridView.Columns.Add("LavWomen", "Women");
        mainDataGridView.Columns.Add("LavTotal", "Total");
        mainDataGridView.Columns.Add("App", "Appliances");
        mainDataGridView.Columns.Add("Stations", "Stations");
        mainDataGridView.Columns.Add("Other", "Other");

        for (int i = 2; i < mainDataGridView.ColumnCount - 3; i++)
        {
            mainDataGridView.Columns[i].Width = 75;
        }
        mainDataGridView.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        mainDataGridView.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        mainDataGridView.Columns[8].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        mainDataGridView.Columns[9].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        mainDataGridView.Columns[10].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

        mainDataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing;
        mainDataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight = mainDataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight * 2;
        mainDataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
        mainDataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        mainDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        mainDataGridView.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
        mainDataGridView.DataSource = dataGridTable; //<---DATASOURCE
        mainDataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(75, 65, 65);
        mainDataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220);
        mainDataGridView.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100);
        mainDataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Calibri", 9, FontStyle.Regular);
        mainDataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
        mainDataGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
        mainDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        mainDataGridView.CellPainting += new DataGridViewCellPaintingEventHandler(mainDataGridView_CellPainting);
        mainDataGridView.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(mainDataGridView_Paint);
        mainDataGridView.GridColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 80, 70);
```

And here is the code where I send the user-entered information to the calculations class:

```
AddRowFrm addrowFrm = new AddRowFrm();
            addrowFrm.ShowDialog();
            if (addrowFrm.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                int[] newRowInfo = addrowFrm.NewRow;

                dataGridTable.ImportRow(ItemDetails.Calculate(newRowInfo[0], newRowInfo[1], newRowInfo[2], newRowInfo[3], newRowInfo[4]));

            }
```

Comment: Post your code please?  I am good with grids etc, but need to know how you are binding etc.

Comment: @Trey I've included the code where I build the `DataGridView` and code where I import the calculated data into the `DataTable`.

Comment: What kind of DataRow is returned by Calculate? Has this DataRow the same columns as your table?  Also why you use ImportRow instead of adding the DataRow returned by Calculate to the DataTable.Rows collection using the Add method?

Comment: @Steve `Calculate()` returns a `DataRow`. It has the exact same number of columns as the `DataTable` and `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 0):

Check how you are binding to the DataTable and that the DataTable contains the same columns as the DataGridView (same column name, datatypes etc.).

Also, are you using the DataSource property of the DataGridView to bind to your DataTable?

Check out MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info on using the DataGridView.

Comment: Yes, the `DataTable` and `DataGridView` have the exact same column names. I hook up the two using the `DataTable` as a DataSource for the `DataGridView`.

Comment: John, When you debug your code, do you get a correct datarow returned to the dataGridTable by your Calculate method?  If so, then its just a binding issue.

Comment: mjay. Yes sir, I get the correct data in my `DataTable`. I believe I've figured it out; and you are right, it has to do with binding the data properly. I will post the solution in a minute. Thank you for your reply:)

Answer (score 0):

I think for your case its better when adding the information to the data table, bind the datagridview to it in the next step:
1-enter information to form
2-add the information as new row in the data table
2-bind the datagrid to data table.

Answer (score 0):

So as mjay said, it was just a issue with binding the data properly.

All I had to do was set the `DataPropertyName` to the column name of the `DataTable`, like so:

```
        mainDataGridView.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "OType";
        mainDataGridView.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "OLoad";
        //...etc
```

Thank you all for your responses and helping me to arrive at a solution:)